# Change color on select > option change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying some very basic stuff, but I can't get my head around it...

Very simple, but I'm going circle: I want the background of the BODY in my page to change to orange when the OPTION with the RESET text associated with it is selected.

If it's a number (1, 2 or 3), the background becomes white.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/PQW88/2/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var reset = $('option:selected').text();

    if (reset === 'reset') {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
    else {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
    }

});
```

Can't seem to target it correctly since it's always orange, without any errors...

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: You don't listen to `change` event!

Comment: Oh...  How would that translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to detect whenever your select value has been changed:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('select').on('change',function() {
        var reset = $('option:selected').text();
        if (reset === 'reset') {
            $('body').css('background-color', 'orange');
        }
        else {
            $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
        }
    });

});
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PQW88/)

Answer (score 2):

You have not used this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
  var reset = $('option:selected').text();
  if (reset === 'reset') {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'orange');
  } else {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
  }
}
```

All you needed was `select` and its `change` event. Then the function would go on.